# Pointers in bidimensional array

Tags: c

I have this code for matrix multiplication, but its given me a compilation error. I need t have a function that receives as arguments the pointers for the 3 matrices and their dimension N.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 100

void matrixmul(int **matA, int **matB, int **matC, int n){

    int i,j,k;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){   
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        matC[i][j] = 0;
        for(k=0;k<n;k++){
        matC[i][j] += matA[i][k] * matB[k][j];
        }
    }
    }

}

int main(){

    int matA[N][N]={1};
    int matB[N][N]={3};
    int matC[N][N];

    int i,j,k;

    matrixmul(&matA, &matB, &matC, N);

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){   
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        printf("%d ", matC[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

The error is:

```
teste.c: In function ‘main’:
teste.c:28:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘matrixmul’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
teste.c:5:6: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[100][100]’
teste.c:28:5: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘matrixmul’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
teste.c:5:6: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[100][100]’
teste.c:28:5: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘matrixmul’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
teste.c:5:6: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[100][100]’
```

Comment: matrixmul(matA, matB, matC, N);

Comment: @n.m. why? there is an indirection more in his sintax

Comment: @JekyllL try it and tell us all how well it worked for you.

Comment: Have you made an effort to *understand* what the error messages *say*?

Comment: @n.m. error message... or warning message? I am going to try

Comment: @Jekyll all warnings are errors *unless you understand precisely what they mean and why it's OK to leave them alone*.

Comment: @n.m I tried... -1 for me... I had to do some extra  work to pass the matrix and work with the pointer....

Comment: 'int**' p can be seen as an array to pointers to integer while the col vector doesn't have any pointer but it has integers inside so the matrix will never decay to 'int**' but to int*[]. In order to use 'int**' the only trick I found is creating a new object... @n.m. I learned the lesson :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Pointers are not arrays*.
All of the `&matA`, `&matB` and `&matC` are of type `int (*)[100][100]` (pointer to an array of 100 arrays of 100 integers) but your function  `matrixmul` is expecting parameters of type `int **` (except for `N`: `int` type).
Change your function definition to

```
void matrixmul(int (*matA)[N], int (*matB)[N], int (*matC)[N], int n){ ... }
```

and call it from `main` as

```
 matrixmul(matA, matB, matC, N);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try these changes.

```
void matrixmul(int matA[][N], int matB[][N], int matC[][N], int n)
```

and can call this function like this

```
matrixmul(matA, matB, matC, N);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the fact that a pointer to a pointer is different by an array. An array is a fixed-length collection of objects, which are stored sequentially in memory. An pointer to a pointer even if it can be used as as an array the compiler doesn't guarantee that the memory of the 2d matrix is continuous. 
One way to decalare your fonction is:

`void matrixmul(int matA[][N], int matB[][N], int matC[][N], int n)`

If you want to pass de matrix as a pointer to a pointer you have to alloc the memory like this:

```
int **array = new int *[N];

for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)

    array[i] = new int[N];`
```